# Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state. (corrupt index issue)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

```
select * from SaleMaster
```

Can't even able to just view the table......
from my knowledge I know where the error occurred.
I have a clustered and non clustered index in this table
Indexs

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SaleMaster] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_SaleMaster] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [salesmanRefIdIX] ON [dbo].[SaleMaster]
(
    [salesmanRefId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [WholesaleBillingMasterRefIdIX] ON [dbo].[SaleMaster]
(
    [WholesaleBillingMasterRefId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO



CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [WholesaleBillingMasterNewRefIdIX] ON [dbo].[SaleMaster]
(
    [WholesaleBillingMasterNewRefId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Daily night I have a job to rebuild these indexes
but due to power issue the system shutdown and the indexes got corrupted

I have tried disbale,rebuilt,reorganise,drop nothing worked.

I have tried  this suspect querys also

**Step 1** Execute In SQL Query Both Two Line

```
EXEC sp_resetstatus 'yourDBname';
ALTER DATABASE yourDBname SET EMERGENCY
```

**Step 2** Refresh Database.then Execute Next Two Line

```
DBCC checkdb('yourDBname')
ALTER DATABASE yourDBname SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

**Step 3** Refresh Database.then Execute Next Two Line

```
DBCC CheckDB ('yourDBname', REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)
ALTER DATABASE yourDBname SET MULTI_USER
```

But nothing worked so far.....
And finally I tried to use some 3rd party software like Stellar Phoenix SQL Database Repair (it shows the data) so is there any way to get this data back??
I just want the data no need of primary keys r anything just I need the data

Comment: Please update your question with the results of dbcc checkdb

Comment: Msg 596, Level 21, State 1, Line 0
Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state.
Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

Comment: So you get this error not while selecting from your table but when executing dbcc checkdb, or in both cases?

Comment: it's in both case

Comment: Try to select this way: select top 10 * from SaleMaster  with(nolock)

Comment: i can't even select top 1 * from salemaster with(nolock)

Comment: I think metadata of this table is corrupted. You should restore from the last backup into another db and copy this table from restored database

Comment: i dont have last backup....is there any other way??
bcz  Stellar Phoenix SQL Database Repair can able to view the data......